# simple JSF commandButton not hitting the action

Tags: jsf

I have the simplest little JSF example (JSF2 with GlassFish) and I can't figure out why the command button is not hitting the action method.  This is what I have ... when I click the button, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

testForm.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:form>
        <h:messages />
        <p/>
        <h:inputText />
        <p/>
        <h:commandButton value="test1" action="#{testController.action1}" />
    </h:form>


</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>testController</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.app.controller.TestController</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>

</faces-config>
```

TestController.java

```
package com.app.controller;

public class TestController {

    public String action1() {
        return "testPage2";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eureka!  After rebuilding the Eclipse project from scratch I realize what I did wrong.  Apache MyFaces is in the project path and the app is being deployed on GlassFish which has it's own JSF implementation.  The two JSF implementations don't want to play nicely together.

What a pain.  And, you know, I made this exact same mistake once before.  Eclipse should warn you about this or there should be some error reported in the GlassFish log or the h:messages tag.

Comment: One more example why it's so important to mention in your question which JSF impl/version you're using. Exactly same question has been asked and answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823719/making-glassfish-respond-to-ajax-request-jsf-2

Answer (score -1):

1)For JSF2.0, Its not required to configure managed bean in Facesconfig.xml.

2)can use @managedban annotation.

```
   package com.app.controller;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    @ManagedBean(name = "testController")
    @SessionScoped
    public class TestController {
        public String action1() {
            return "testPage2";
        }
/** Constructor, getters and setters*/
    }
```

Comment: This does not explain the problem. The old fashioned faces-config declaration should work as good in JSF2.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with both annotations and faces-config and it doesn't hit the action method.  Also, the bean is configured correctly because I added a simple property to return a "test string" and it is being returned fine.  No idea why it isn't hitting the action method. :(