# Glassfish - ajax does not work

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, tomcat, glassfish

I've done the migration from Tomcat to Glassfish and now my ajax requests does not work. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823719/making-glassfish-respond-to-ajax-request-jsf-2) I changed the settings glassfish-web.xml file such as there, but it did not help. I'm use JSF 2 with OpenFaces.

```
<o:selectBooleanCheckbox id="addTitleC" value="#{ajaxBean.editTitle}">
    <o:ajax event="click" render=":form:titleText" />
</o:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

AjaxBean source:

```
public void setEditTitle(boolean editTitle) {
    this.editTitle = editTitle;
}

public boolean isEditTitle() {
    return editTitle;
}
```

except for the change file settings glassfish-web.xml I changed nothing, and everything worked in Tomcat.

EDIT: This what i have from Glassfish:

```
<partial-response>
  <error>
   <error-name>class java.lang.IllegalStateException</error-name>
   <error-message>org.openfaces.component.ajax.AjaxHelper</error-message>
  </error>
  <changes>
    <extension ln="openfaces" ajaxResult="null" type="ajaxResult"></extension>
  </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Glassfish stack trace:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: org.openfaces.component.ajax.AjaxHelper
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:150)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreAttachedState(UIComponentBase.java:1785)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreBehaviorsState(UIComponentBase.java:2136)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1571)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.restoreState(UIOutput.java:256)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.restoreState(UIInput.java:1404)
    at org.openfaces.component.OUIInputBase.restoreState(OUIInputBase.java:274)
    at org.openfaces.component.select.SelectBooleanCheckbox.restoreState(SelectBooleanCheckbox.java:348)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1336)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1351)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1351)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processRestoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1351)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processRestoreState(UIViewRoot.java:879)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:208)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:453)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:148)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:192)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: have you checked the firebug or webconsole?

Comment: Just read the server log for the full stack trace.

Comment: look at my stack trace

Comment: Wow, nasty one. Are you using an `AjaxHelper` instance anywhere in your own code? If not, then report it as an issue to OpenFaces guys.

Comment: I don't use this class anywhere in my code, I'm trying to create RIA with one page that will use ajax requests, maybe I must change my plans about this web application to multi-page.